# Vertical scrubber line using chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to get a vertical scrubber line when hovering over a line chart using chart.js v2?  Similar to the way a vertical line appears using this rickshaw example: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/formatter.html

I can use tool tips on the actual points along the line, but it'd like to be able to have a vertical line appear as the user hovers over the chart and scrubs left to right

Answer (score 2):

You can extend Chart.js to do this. Just override the `showTooltip` method after initializing the chart.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var originalShowTooltip = this.showTooltip;
        this.showTooltip = function (activePoints) {

            if (activePoints.length) {
                var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                var scale = this.scale;
                ctx.save();
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(activePoints[0].x, scale.startPoint);
                ctx.lineTo(activePoints[0].x, scale.endPoint);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            }

            return originalShowTooltip.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

and then

```
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/98gz1fhw/

Comment: This is fantastic and works perfectly with Chart.js 1.x.  Wondering if the same sort of thing can be done with Chart.js version 2 (still in beta)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes (Chart.js 2 also has extensions - https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/v2.0-dev/docs/07-Advanced.md). Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with the code yet. Sorry! Will give a shot over the weekend though.